# Parameters in Powershell merging when using brackets to call a function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass two parameters to a function in PowerShell and i'm finding odd results.  As I pass my parameters into a function and output them in a combined string, all parameters are displayed at the point of the first parameter.

heres my code:

```
$s = "D:\"
$o = "I:\"

function a($source, $output){
    Write-Output $source
    Write-Output $output
    Write-Output "exe $source --parameter $output"
}


Write-Output $s
Write-Output $o
Write-Output "exe $s --parameter $o"

a($s, $o)
```

the output:

```
D:\
I:\
exe D:\ --parameter I:\
D:\
I:\
exe D:\ I:\ --parameter
```

> Notice "I:\" is in a different place

I want to call the function and get this output:

```
D:\
I:\
exe D:\ --parameter I:\
```

Can anyone help me work out how to avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

I've just worked out that if I call my function without brackets and commas it works how I want it to.

```
a $s $o
```

outputs:

```
D:\
I:\
exe D:\ --parameter I:\
```

Comment: this is very consufing. I wonder why powershell does not allow common syntax and causes this weird mess with parameters

Comment: [this might help](https://serverfault.com/a/820149/429274) @McVitas.  "The interpreter sees parenthesis as a control structure"