# Problem with Powershell variable substitution in Strings

Tags: string, powershell, variables, substitution

I have the following Powershell function, which prepares a query I want to use for a request against an API.

```
function getUserID ([String]$loginName, [String] $firstName, [String] $lastName, [String] $employeeId)
{
    $queryText = "loginid:$loginName vorname:$firstName nachname:$lastname personalnummer:$employeeId"
    $requestData = (@{
        "query" = "$queryText"
    } | ConvertTo-Json)
    return $requestData
}
```

If I call it like this:

```
$test = getUserID("blibla", "Bli", "Bla", "34654")
$test
```

I would expect the following output:

```
{
    "query": "loginid:blibla vorname:Bli nachname:Bla personalnummer:34654"
}
```

But the actual output looks like this:

```
{
    "query": "loginid:blibla Bli Bla 34654 vorname: nachname: personalnummer:"
}
```

I don't understand why the variable substitution seems to break after the first substitution. Or at least it doesn't behave the way, I would expect it to.

Any help is appreciated!

**Solution:** wrong function call.
It should be:

```
getUserID "blibla" "Bli" "Bla" "34654"
```

Comment: Wrong argument-passing syntax, PowerShell is not C# :) `getUserID("blibla", "Bli", "Bla", "34654")` -> `getUserID "blibla" "Bli" "Bla" "34654"`

Comment: Besides, note that [the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet has default depth of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/1701026)

Comment: Some duplicates... https://stackoverflow.com/a/11061342/3156906 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276244/parameters-in-powershell-merging-when-using-brackets-to-call-a-function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793891/how-to-use-powershell-function-parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988226/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-into-a-function-in-powershell

Comment: In short: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
See the linked duplicates for details.